# Hdfs Snappy corrupted data. Could not decompress data. Input is invalid. When does this occur and can it be prevented?

Tags: scala, hadoop, hdfs, snappy

I am writing data into hdfs with the following code:

```
def createOrAppendHadoopSnappy(path: Path, hdfs: FileSystem): CompressionOutputStream = {
  val compressionCodecFactory = new CompressionCodecFactory(hdfs.getConf)
  val snappyCodec = compressionCodecFactory.getCodecByClassName(classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec].getName)
  snappyCodec.createOutputStream(createOrAppend(path, hdfs))
}

def createOrAppend(path: Path, hdfs: FileSystem): FSDataOutputStream = {
  if (hdfs.exists(path)) {
    hdfs.append(path)
  } else {
    hdfs.create(path)
  }
}
```

and the code calling this function is roughly:

```
...
val outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(HdfsUtils.createOrAppendHadoopSnappy(filePath, fileSystem))
...
for(managedOutputStream <- managed(outputStream)) {
  IOUtils.writeLines(lines.asJavaCollection, "\n", managedOutputStream, "UTF-8")
}
...
```

Now at one point I have had a few files which were corrupted with the following message when I read them with 'hadoop fs -text':
java.lang.InternalError: Could not decompress data. Input is invalid.

Note that this code runs with Spark on YARN and due to some changes in the code the job was killed by yarn once and I also once manually killed the spark job in a test later.

Now I wanted to try to reproduce the scenario where the corrupt files are generated, but so far I did not succeed. I tried different things where the writing would be interrupted (with System.exit(0), an exception, manual ctrl-c). The file was not fully written, but it was not giving the java InteralError exception.

Does anyone know in which cases the corrupted files and happen and how/if they can be prevented?

Comment: I am also experiencing Snappy corrupted data with the error "Could not decompress data. Input is invalid". In my case unfortunately it happened at very last reduce step of a long running job. Did you find out the root cause of this?

Comment: Nope, I haven't been working on this since.

Comment: I think in my case the root cause was yarn killing the job while spark was writing data. I probably could try to make a reproducible scenario when I have some time. There are probably other possibilities of corrupted data occuring though.